# Should we delete/merge the [sc2-build-order] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merging

Is [sc2-build-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sc2-build-order) a legacy tag that should be deleted, or is there a reason it still exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the build order tag, merging those questions tagged with it into starcraft-2 if they aren't already. There's no point in requiring people to favorite multiple tags for SC2 information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be allowed to stay. It's a little general, but build orders are a big part of SC2 strategy, and I can see people using this tag, searching for it, favoriting it, etc.

On the down side, it is a little generic, and I don't think tags like [sc2-strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sc2-strategy), [sc2-micro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sc2-micro), or in general [gamename-tactictype](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamename-tactictype) are a good idea. I **especially** don't think we should have a [build-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-order) tag.

But as I said, build orders are rather key to SC2, and we have a lot of SC2 content so it's probably okay to have some sub-tags, like how Diablo 3 has [diablo-3-monk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-monk), etc.

Comment: we already have [terran],[zerg] and [protoss], why can't build order questions simply be tagged with the race you're playing?

Comment: This answer seems to be in contrast to [LessPop_MoreFizz's answer here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8567/2578).  Or is this one of the exceptions?  If so, why?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I think that @LessPopMoreFizz is mainly speaking against truly generic tags, like `strategy`. I think Starcraft 2 is one of the exceptions to this rule, due to its popularity here, and the distinct nature of its races. I would argue that build orders are as fundamental as races, and so this tag is useful and warranted. But I could go either way.

Comment: We also have [tf2-sniper], [tf2-heavy] etc for team fortress character strategies, and I imagine games like LoL or WoW probably have similar character based subtags, although I've never played either. I think the race tags should be split into [sc1-*] & [sc2-*], because at the moment they're used for both sc1 and 2

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not sure `zerg` should become `sc2-zerg`. If anyone wants to find Starcraft 2 Zerg content, they can search using both `starcraft-2` and `zerg`. But that is a separate issue.

Answer (score -2):

I do not see it adding any real value to the questions. Especially in its current form.

If it does not get removed (burning it would be my vote), maybe it should be changed to just [build-order] so it can be used with more than just starcraft 2 (other RTS games and MOBAs for example)

As-is it is used in 26 questions. There are 155 [questions mentioning build order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=build-order+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: -1 for making it *more* generic.

Comment: We don't do generic tags well

Comment: Not to mention I haven't seen a Moba that uses build-orders...

Comment: @lyrion LoL and DOTA use build orders all the time for things like item purchasing/crafting items & skill point allocation.

Comment: @ColinD I see those as "builds", build orders I see as creating minions and buildings, not as crafting items and class levels tho.